# iOS9 multitasking in split view - notification when another app opens keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ios9

My app receives UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and related notifications when it's the focused app. But if another app is focused in the split multitasking view, it no longer receives it. I was testing this in simulator since my physical device don't support split view.

Is this a known simulator bug? Am I missing some configuration options? Does it work as expected on iPad Air 2?

Comment: Is it still happening as of Xcode 7.3?

Answer (score 2):

The expected functionality is actually that your app, even when it is not focused, will receive keyboard notifications.

It is mentioned in [Getting Started with Multitasking on iPad in iOS 9 WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=205) at 29:45.

Comment: That's what I thought. But when running in iOS Simulator, it's not getting the notifications. I wonder if it's Simulator-specific bug or an issue with my code.